# Simple prisoner's dilemma genetic algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I have used an existing genetic algorithm from
[here](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/creating-a-genetic-algorithm-for-beginners/3)
and reworked it I but don't know what I'm doing wrong
This is the error that I get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   simpleGa.Algorithm.crossover(Algorithm.java:69)   at
>   simpleGa.Algorithm.evolvePopulation(Algorithm.java:34)    at
>   simpleGa.GAprisonerdilemma.main(GAprisonerdilemma.java:41)

I can't figure out exactly where the mistake is. Read a lot about `NullPointerException` but couldn't figure it out

```
package simpleGa;

public class Population {

     public static Individual[] individuals;

     /*
      * Constructors
      */
     // Create a population
     public Population(int populationSize, boolean initialise) {
         individuals = new Individual[populationSize];
         // Initialise population
         if (initialise) {
             // Loop and create individuals
             for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
                 Individual newIndividual = new Individual();
                 newIndividual.generateIndividual();
                 saveIndividual(i, newIndividual);
             }
             for(int i=0;i<size();i++)
             {
                 if(i%2==1){Individual individual1=individuals[i-1];
                 Individual individual2=individuals[i];
              if(individuals[i-1].getGene(i-1)==0 && individuals[i].getGene(i)==0){
                individuals[i-1].fitness=individual1.fitness+1;
                individuals[i].fitness=individual2.fitness+1;
             }
             if(individuals[i-1].getGene(i-1)==1 && individuals[i].getGene(i)==1){
                 individuals[i-1].fitness=individual1.fitness+2;
                 individuals[i].fitness=individual2.fitness+2;
             }
             if(individuals[i-1].getGene(i-1)==0 && individuals[i].getGene(i)==1){
                 individuals[i-1].fitness=individual1.fitness+3;
                 individuals[i].fitness=individual2.fitness+0;
             }
             if(individuals[i-1].getGene(i-1)==1 && individuals[i].getGene(i)==0){
                 individuals[i-1].fitness=individual1.fitness+0;
                 individuals[i].fitness=individual2.fitness+3;
             } 

         }}}



     }

     /* Getters */
     public Individual getIndividual(int index) {
         return individuals[index];
     }

     public Individual getFittest() {
         Individual fittest = individuals[0];
         // Loop through individuals to find fittest
         for (int i = 1; i < size(); i++) {
             if (fittest.getFitness() <= getIndividual(i).getFitness()) {
                 fittest = getIndividual(i);
             }
         }
         return fittest;
     }

     /* Public methods */
     // Get population size
     public int size() {
         return individuals.length;
     }

     // Save individual
     public void saveIndividual(int index, Individual indiv) {
         individuals[index] = indiv;
     }
 }

package simpleGa;

public class Individual {

     static int defaultGeneLength = 1000;
     private long[] genes =new long [defaultGeneLength];
     // Cache
     public static int fitness = 0;

     // Create a random individual
     public void generateIndividual() {
         for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
             long gene =  Math.round(Math.random());
             genes[i] = gene;
         }
     }

     /* Getters and setters */
     // Use this if you want to create individuals with different gene lengths
     public static void setDefaultGeneLength(int length) {
         defaultGeneLength = length;
     }

     public long getGene(int i) {
         return genes[i];
     }

     public void setGene(int index, long value) {
         genes[index] = value;
         fitness = 0;
     }

     /* Public methods */
     public int size() {
         return genes.length;
     }

     public static  int getFitness() {

         return fitness;
     }
     public void setFitness(int i) {

          fitness=i;
     }
     @Override
     public String toString() {
         String geneString = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
             geneString += getGene(i);
         }
         return geneString;
     }
 }

package simpleGa;

public class Algorithm {

     /* GA parameters */
     private static final double uniformRate = 0.5;
     private static final double mutationRate = 0.015;
     private static final int tournamentSize = 5;
     private static final boolean elitism = true;

     /* Public methods */

     // Evolve a population
     public static Population evolvePopulation(Population pop) {
         Population newPopulation = new Population(pop.size(), false);

         // Keep our best individual
         if (elitism) {
             newPopulation.saveIndividual(0, pop.getFittest());
         }

         // Crossover population
         int elitismOffset;
         if (elitism) {
             elitismOffset = 1;
         } else {
             elitismOffset = 0;
         }
         // Loop over the population size and create new individuals with
         // crossover
         for (int i = elitismOffset; i < pop.size(); i++) {
             Individual indiv1 = tournamentSelection(pop);
             Individual indiv2 = tournamentSelection(pop);
             Individual newIndiv = crossover(indiv1, indiv2);
             newPopulation.saveIndividual(i, newIndiv);
         }

         // Mutate population
         for (int i = elitismOffset; i < newPopulation.size(); i++) {
             mutate(newPopulation.getIndividual(i));
         }
         for(int i=0;i<pop.size();i++)
     {for(int j=0;j<pop.getIndividual(i).size();j++)
         {if(i%2==1){Individual individual1=Population.individuals[i-1];
         Individual individual2=Population.individuals[i];
      if(Population.individuals[i-1].getGene(i-1)==0 && Population.individuals[i].getGene(i)==0){
        Population.individuals[i-1].fitness=individual1.fitness+1;
        Population.individuals[i].fitness=individual2.fitness+1;
     }
     if(Population.individuals[i-1].getGene(i-1)==1 && Population.individuals[i].getGene(i)==1){
         Population.individuals[i-1].fitness=individual1.fitness+2;
         Population.individuals[i].fitness=individual2.fitness+2;
     }
     if(Population.individuals[i-1].getGene(i-1)==0 && Population.individuals[i].getGene(i)==1){
         Population.individuals[i-1].fitness=individual1.fitness+3;
         Population.individuals[i].fitness=individual2.fitness+0;
     }
     if(Population.individuals[i-1].getGene(i-1)==1 && Population.individuals[i].getGene(i)==0){
         Population.individuals[i-1].fitness=individual1.fitness+0;
         Population.individuals[i].fitness=individual2.fitness+3;
     } }}}``
         return newPopulation;
     }

     // Crossover individuals
     private static Individual crossover(Individual indiv1, Individual indiv2) {
         Individual newSol = new Individual();
         // Loop through genes
         for (int i = 0; i < indiv1.size(); i++) {
             // Crossover
             if (Math.random() <= uniformRate) {
                 newSol.setGene(i, indiv1.getGene(i));
             } else {
                 newSol.setGene(i, indiv2.getGene(i));
             }
         }
         return newSol;
     }

     // Mutate an individual
     private static void mutate(Individual indiv) {
         // Loop through genes
         for (int i = 0; i < indiv.size(); i++) {
             if (Math.random() <= mutationRate) {
                 // Create random gene
                 long gene =  Math.round(Math.random());
                 indiv.setGene(i, gene);
             }
         }
     }

     // Select individuals for crossover
     private static Individual tournamentSelection(Population pop) {
         // Create a tournament population
         Population tournament = new Population(tournamentSize, false);
         // For each place in the tournament get a random individual
         for (int i = 0; i < tournamentSize; i++) {
             int randomId = (int) (Math.random() * pop.size());
             tournament.saveIndividual(i, pop.getIndividual(randomId));
         }
         // Get the fittest
         Individual fittest = tournament.getFittest();
         return fittest;
     }
package simpleGa;

public class FitnessCalc {



     /* Public methods */
     // Set a candidate solution as a byte array

     // To make it easier we can use this method to set our candidate solution 
     // with string of 0s and 1s

     // Calculate inidividuals fittness by comparing it to our candidate solution
     static int getFitness(Individual individual) {
         int fitness = 0;
         // Loop through our individuals genes and compare them to our cadidates
     fitness=Individual.fitness;
         return fitness;
     }
}
     // Get optimum fitness

     }
package simpleGa;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GAprisonerdilemma {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set a candidate solution
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Input number of games!");
         int k = keyboard.nextInt();
        Individual.setDefaultGeneLength(k);
       // Create an initial population
        System.out.println("Input number of individuals in the population!");
         int p = keyboard.nextInt();
        Population myPop = new Population(p, true);

        System.out.println("Input acceptable number of generations!");
         int l = keyboard.nextInt();

       // Evolve our population until we reach an optimum solution
       int generationCount = 0;
       int j=l+1;
       System.out.println("Input requiered fitness value !");
         int f = keyboard.nextInt();
         int h=0;
        // Evolve our population until we reach an optimum solution

         for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
            {

                if(i==0){}
                else{

                if(myPop.getFittest().getFitness()>=f){if(h==0){h++;}
                else{ System.out.println("Solution found!");
                System.out.println("Generation: " + generationCount);
                System.out.println( "Fitness(Points): " + myPop.getFittest().getFitness());
                break;}
               }else {myPop = Algorithm.evolvePopulation(myPop);
               generationCount++;
               System.out.println("Generation: " + generationCount + " Fittest: " + myPop.getFittest().getFitness());
               }
                if(i==j-1){ if(myPop.getFittest().getFitness()>=f)System.out.println("Solution found !");
                else System.out.println("Solution not found closest solution is!");
                System.out.println("Generation: " + generationCount);
                System.out.println( " Fitness(Points): " + myPop.getFittest().getFitness());}

                }


            }

            System.out.println("0 for betrays in that turn 1 for cooperates!");
            System.out.println("Turns:");
            System.out.println(myPop.getFittest());
    }
}
```

Comment: indiv1 or indiv2 is null in Algorithm.crossover(). The logic there is also broken as you are only checking the size of one individual, what if the second is smaller/larger?

Comment: sorry didn't upload the right code now it's correct and it worked in the original code of genetic algorithm like this and all the individuals are the same size

Comment: Same thing as before, one of them is null. It is also good practice to start doing error checks in your code like nulls checks and looking for equalities. It will help avoid crashes and make debugging easier.

Comment: I got that one of them is null but I don't get why nor do I have a clue how to fix it